# how to set position value of spinner according to clickable position of spinner by another spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

i am trying to implement spinner position according to the position of other spinner ,these two spinners are in different fragments. these fragments are on tabhost. please help me hoe to do that.

this is my code

```
             ArrayAdapter<String> arradp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, deviceidlist);

            spinner.setAdapter(arradp);
              String nme = ApplicationData.gettabalias();
            if(!nme.equals(null)){
                int position = arradp.getPosition(nme);
                spinner.setSelection(position);
            }
```

Comment: Use onItemClickListener in your first spinner to change the position of second spinner.

Comment: @Pushpa Latha Use OnItemSelectedListener for spinner and if position selected communicate Fragment to help of interface or EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) try

Comment: yes i used onitemselected listener only..in onitemselectedlistener of first spinner,i was send item position through getters and setters ,